# java.sql.SQLException: Statement has already been closed during call to executeBatch()

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

There are millions of records which are added using prepared statement `addBatch()` and executed using `executeBatch()` and it throws the error as below.

> java.sql.SQLException: Statement has already been closed
>           at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.checkStatement(Statement.java:318)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.preInvocationHandler(Statement.java:123)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:188)

As from the above we can see that it happens during the call to `executeBatch()`- `PreparedStatement`.
What can be done to overcome it?

Tried `setQueryTimeout` - didn't help.

code -

```
 //function123  called by parent function. 
 //Argument -1  "Connection conn" - spent considerable amount of time in previous methods
 //Argument -2  "List plans" - The list has around a million records(plans)
 //
 private void function123(Connection conn, List plans) throws Exception {

   //Connection opened from parent function..
   //It is expected to load data in multiple tables and connection has to be retained until all tables gets loaded.

    try {
        // Create the Prepared Statement for the Insert SQL created
        ppdBatchStmt = new AREPreparedStatement(conn, SQL);

        for (Iterator A = plans.iterator(); A.hasNext();) {

            ppdBatchStmt.setString(2, ...);

            ppdBatchStmt.setLong(3, ...);
            ppdBatchStmt.setString(4, ...);
            ppdBatchStmt.setDouble(5, ...);
            .....
            ....
            ....
            ppdBatchStmt.addBatch();
     }
            // Execute the prepared Statement
            int[] insertedRows = ppdBatchStmt.executeBatch();

   catch (RuntimeException runEx) {

    } finally {
            if (ppdBatchStmt != null) ppdBatchStmt.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Let show your source code, and insert command `printStackTrace()` of Exception, then post it.

Comment: Millions of records may just be too much for a single batch. How about splitting it up to like ten thousand per batch or so? You can still keep it in a single transaction (although I guess there are some size limits with that as well).

Comment: Going to try splitting up the batch option.But also want to know what actually caused the error to be reported

Comment: Without code and a [mcve] this is hard to diagnose. If I had to guess, this is likely a lease timeout (or similar) where weblogic forcibly revoked your connection because it was in use (leased) for too long. You may want to check the data source config.